# Determinate existence and compute (if exists): $\lim_{(x,y) \to (1,0)} \frac{\cos{\sqrt{|xy|}}-1}{y}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Compute the following limit:
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (1,0)} \frac{\cos{\sqrt{|xy|}}-1}{y}$$

I need help computing this limit.

**My try:**

\begin{align*}
&\lim_{(x,y) \to (1,0)} \frac{\cos{\sqrt{|xy|}}-1}{y}\\
= &\lim_{(x,y) \to (1,0)} \frac{x\cos{\sqrt{|xy|}}-1}{xy}\\
= &\lim_{(x,y) \to (1,0)} x \cdot \lim_{(x,y) \to (1,0)} \frac{\cos{\sqrt{|xy|}}-1}{xy}\\
= &\lim_{u \to 0} \frac{\cos{\sqrt{u}}-1}{u}\\
= & -\frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

Where I used the continuity of the functions and existence of the limits to conclude the result after replacing $xy=u$. However, I think this is not correct, because with this replacement I am "forgetting" the absolute value of the function, but I don't know how to conclude this idea. It's this the correct answer and the approach is incorrect? or the limit doesn't exists?.

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Why not consider $u \rightarrow 0^+$, and $u \rightarrow 0^-$ separately? leave √|u|.

Comment: Yes you can verify it $cos(\sqrt(|xy¦) =1-(xy)^2/2 +o((xy)^2) $ gives your results.

Comment: @PeterSzilas In that  case, the limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Option :

Multiplying numerator and denominator by $\cos \sqrt{|xy|} +1$.

$\frac{\sin ^2 (\sqrt{|xy|})}{y(\cos (\sqrt {|xy|})+1)}=$

$(|xy|/y)\frac{\sin^2 (\sqrt{|xy|})}{(\sqrt{|xy|})^2}\frac{1}{\cos (\sqrt {|xy|})+1}.$

Second and third factor are no problem.

Look at $\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (1,0^\pm)} |x|(|y|/y)$.

Hence?